# Constructing algorithm/formula

Tags: algorithm, formula

I am constructing a racing simulator and need help with ideas on how to construct the formula.

Each race have eight competitors, each and everyone of these are designated a starting track. Track 1 is considered the best, track 2 the next best and so on.

However if a racer has a low value in acceleration and given starting track 1; this is a clear disadvantage as there is a overwhelming risk that he might be trapped and not able to finish in a strong position.

If the racer at track 1 has an average value of acceleration he is still at a disadvantage if the racer at track 2 possesses a higher value.

The participant at track 8 needs to be pretty much faster than all the other competitors to reach the lead.

Does anyone have ideas on how I would go about to construct a formula like this? I'm basically looking for the way to think and I gladly appreciate all the input I get

Comment: A formula to calculate *what*?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you right, i might formulate it something like this.
A racing car has an acceleration value and a starting position (track?). Every race consists of a certain amount of laps on a track, where the track has a certain length.

At the end of the simulation each car finishes with a certain time in which it completed all necessary laps. I would propose to just offset each car a certain time, depending on their starting position. For example, position 1 offset +0s, position 2 offset +2s, position 3 offset +4s.
I would also introduce some sort of 'end speed' or 'total speed' for each type of car, so that you can just calculate the time with acceleration, total speed and number of laps times the total lenght of the track.